# How to define an array of objects in a .env file?

Tags: json, angular, config

The following is the expected json object to be loaded in my Angular app from the **.env** file:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
]
```

If I add the following variable, my Angular app crashes because the parsing to JSON gets broken:

```
ENV_VARIABLE: '[{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}]'
```

The error complains about the "," in between the two objects.

Comment: Does this not work?

{
 “Values”: [
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Why would like to load json from env file? See if you can have it in a file and store the path in env and read it from the file when the application loads.

Answer (score 1):

What you did works fine for me with Angular v9, I just removed the single quotes - see below.

Environment

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  ENV_VARIABLE: [{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}] 
  //remove the single quotes
};
```

And in controller

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    let x = environment.ENV_VARIABLE;
 }
```

All works fine no errors.